# What kind of damage do Firewalkers do?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is it considered fire damage?  If so, is it affected by "Fire skills deal 20% more damage"?

Comment: I would like to if they are affected by attack speed and weapon dmg. It seems they do benefit from general damage +%.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fire Walkers burn effect does indeed benefit from +%fire damage on items.

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/23aiyu/which_legendary_procs_are_affected_by_elemental/)

[Source2](http://www.diablohub.com/database/sorting/benefit-from-elemental-damage)(Thanks @Bob2Chiv)

Comment: This is interesting to me, because I heard the exact opposite. Since it isn't a 'skill', it arguably shouldn't benefit from +%Fire damage. It appears Blizzard has not announced whether or not this is intended, so it may change if they come around to making things consistent. +1

Comment: There are a few things that are not skills that are affected by elemental damage. Element damage on weapons is an example. They just fixed that bug.

Comment: @Bob2Chiv Blizzard is not known for consistency :P But +%ele damage doesn't (and logically shouldn't) be just for skills, because why would the items even mention the element of effect if it wasn't affected by +%ele dmg.

Comment: I was going to make my own answer, but I'll put it here instead. Here is another source that claims to definitively say which items benefit from +%Elemental damage (includes FireWalkers): http://www.diablohub.com/database/sorting/benefit-from-elemental-damage